Scale clustered chart to use up space in visual - Power BI
I am currently working on a dashboard in Power BI that shows the row counts of tables that can be adjusted with a slider. I have used a clustered chart to create the visual. In principal I have been able to get the output I want. However I would like to finish off the formatting. My problem is that there is excess padding in the visual as shown below.

I would like to get rid of the spaces highlighted in Red. I would like the chart to 'fill' the space. Do you have any tips on how to do this? Thanks in advance

That's because you don't put any field to x-axis. That's by design.
Here is a workaround for you.
create a table.
Table2 = SELECTCOLUMNS({"a","b","c","d","e"},"Category",[Value])

then create a measure
Final measure = 
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE (Table2[Category]),
    "a", [aa],
    "b", [bb],
    "c", [cc],
    "d", [dd]
)



Absolute lifesaver!! I am fairly new to Power BI and have spent the last 2 nights racking my brain on how to do this. Thanks a lot much appreciated.
